# rsync - Exclude directories but include files within them

Tags: linux, rsync

I have an rsync command which I'm using to synchronise two directories:

```
rsync -CurvtOlon --delete /home/source/path/ /home/dest/path/
```

When I run the command, it recursively scans all of the source tree and finds me all of the files and directories which need updating in the destination tree.  When I remove the -n option and actually run the command, it synchronises all of the files and directories as I'd expect, but when I run the command again immediately afterwards it tells me that the files are now up-to-date, but all of the directories still need updating.

I either need to understand why it's not updating the directories properly and still marking them as out-of-date, or I need a new command to compare only files and not directories.

I thought I could try to exclude everything and then include just the file extensions that I know I need, but this seems to prevent it from even looking in directories to find the files in the first place:

```
rsync -CurvtOlon --delete --include="*.txt" --exclude="*" /home/source/path/ /home/dest/path/
```

Any suggestions very welcome!